# How to Integrate Spring 4 with Hibernate Search 5?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have already integrate Spring MVC+ Spring Framework 4 + Hibernate ORM 4.

Now I want to use **full text search** in **hibernate search**.

So, How to Integrate Spring Framework 4 with Hibernate Search 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) this should be as simple as:

1. Add Hibernate Search JAR to the application.
2. Add `<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>` and `<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/var/lucene/indexes"/>` to the Hibernate configuration.  Alternatively, you can [choose a different provider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-directory).
3. Annotate the entities and fields you want to index.
4. If using the Hibernate Session directly, obtain a `FullTextSession` as `Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession())`, or if using an EntityManager, obtain a `FullTextEntityManager` as `Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager)`.  It is assumed that `sessionFactory` or `entityManager` is injected using Spring.
5. Start searching.  Entity instances are automatically indexed on persist so no special steps are required for generating the search indexes.

Give this a try and if you face any specific problem you can raise them as separate questions.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But I have a problem "**SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager**" after adding **@Indexed** to my entities.